# Process singly linked list with OpenMP

Tags: c++, linked-list, openmp

The code I want to parallelize has the following simple form:

```
for(const ListItem* item = myList; item; item = item->getNext())
  doSthWith(item);
```

I compile on MSVC 2013 with omp 2.0 support. Is it possible to still parallelize this in a clean and efficient way? First problem I stumbled upon is that I need an integral loop counter. I could obviously just use an int and assign the pointer inside the loop but this already starts feeling like a kind of dirty workaround.
Is iterating types like this even supported my the omp standard or might this end up in UB anyway?

Comment: If you upgrade to a modern (OpenMP 3.1 or 4.0) compiler, then you could implement it fairly naturally with tasks. (If you're a student, you can get the Intel compiler for free...)

Comment: Yes, I know but unfortunately I'm bound to MSVC. I mean, I'm also ok with workarounds like I mentioned above as long as they obey well defined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not really an answer, but I can't format code in a comment...

Assuming that the list is not being modified, you could write something somewhat unpleasant like this (typed in here, not compiled, not tested).

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int nThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    int me       = omp_get_thread_num();
    int itemNo   = 0;

    for(const ListItem* item = myList; 
        item; 
        (item = item->getNext()), itemNo++)
    {
        if (itemNo%nThreads == me)
        {
            doSthWith(item);
        }
    }
}
```